# ez_setup error while installing gdrivefs

Tags: installation, python

I'm installing GDriveFS using

```
sudo pip install gdrivefs
```

but receive the error

```
ImportError: No module named ez_setup
```

I believe I have all the necessary Python modules. Can you please suggest some other things for me to try or to check so that I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
sudo pip install ez_setup
sudo pip install gdrivefs
```

Comment: I'm getting
    no distributions at all found for ez_setup

Comment: it seems like i may have an incomplete set of python utils etc. would that be a correct assessment? if so, what's the best way to ensure that I have all the necessary packages?